# Angular Kendo grid reactive grid editing add row statusChange subscription not triggered on blur

Tags: angular, validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, subscription

Using status change subscription to update a notification control with validation messages. All works fine except for a newly added row. Tabbing out of an empty required field triggers validation correctly, adds the ng-invalid to the input textbox but does not trigger the statusChange subscription.

It appears the formGroup.status as set to "INVALID" just before displaying the input box. I would guess that the statusChange misses the field going invalid because it is already marked invalid (sigh). Adding and removing a character correctly triggers the subscription.

I used this Kendo example (https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-directives/#toc-reactive-editing-directive) and added the statusChange subscription here in stack blitz (https://angular-5eh2t5.stackblitz.io).

I tried the updateValueAndValidity() as recommended in ([Reactive Form says it is invalid when a new FormGroup is added to a FormArray when it is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576720/reactive-form-says-it-is-invalid-when-a-new-formgroup-is-added-to-a-formarray-wh)) without success.

I know this is a narrow situation but has anyone experienced this and found a work around so that the subscription is triggered on a new item when the ng-invalid is added?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { products } from './products';
import { Product } from './model';
import { CreateFormGroupArgs } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-grid
            [kendoGridReactiveEditing]="createFormGroup"
            [kendoGridBinding]="products"
            [pageSize]="5"
            [pageable]="true"
            [sortable]="true"
            [navigable]="true"
        >
            <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
                <button kendoGridAddCommand>Add new</button>
                formGroup status "{{ formGroup.status }}", {{ statusChanged }} statusChanged subscription events
            </ng-template>
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" editor="numeric" title="Price"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" editor="boolean" title="Discontinued"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="UnitsInStock" editor="numeric" title="Units In Stock"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-command-column title="command" [width]="220">
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-isNew="isNew">
                    <button kendoGridEditCommand [primary]="true">Edit</button>
                    <button kendoGridRemoveCommand>Remove</button>
                    <button kendoGridSaveCommand [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">{{ isNew ? 'Add' : 'Update' }}</button>
                    <button kendoGridCancelCommand>{{ isNew ? 'Discard changes' : 'Cancel' }}</button>
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-command-column>
        </kendo-grid>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
    public products: Product[] = products;
    public formGroup: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        ProductID: null,
        ProductName: '',
        UnitPrice: null,
        UnitsInStock: null,
        Discontinued: false,
    });

    public statusChanged: number = 0;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.createFormGroup = this.createFormGroup.bind(this);
    }

    public createFormGroup(args: CreateFormGroupArgs): FormGroup {
        const item = args.isNew ? new Product() : args.dataItem;

        this.statusChanged = 0;

        this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            ProductID: item.ProductID,
            ProductName: [item.ProductName, Validators.required],
            UnitPrice: item.UnitPrice,
            UnitsInStock: [
                item.UnitsInStock,
                Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1,3}')]),
            ],
            Discontinued: item.Discontinued,
        });

        this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();

        this.formGroup.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
            this.statusChanged++;
        })

        return this.formGroup;
    }
}
```